# Returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I am trying to get the data from this endpoint but I am getting an empty array. Can you help me with this? thanks

I've been trying to do it, with the other methods I have I can get the corresponding data.

I tried several ways but still can't find a solution.

```
http://localhost:8081/getmnemonicsandtagsforabm this is the methood
```

```
const DataTable = () => {
  const provider = useContext(AppContext);

  let [editServiceStatus, setEditServiceStatus] = useState(false);

  let [configServiceStatusButton, setConfigServiceStatusButton] =
    useState(false);

  let [serviceItem_selected, setServiceItem_selected] = useState([]);

  let [fetchServiceDetail, setFetchServiceDetail] = useState([]);

  let sessionID = localStorage.getItem("session_id");

  const [array_services, setArray_services] = useState({ khad_services: [] });

  const [array_services2, setArray_services2] = useState({ khad_services: [] });

  const [active_dropdown, setActive_dropdown] = useState(false);

  const [active_serviceConfig, setActive_serviceConfig] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let session_id = {
      session_id: sessionID,
    };

    fetch("http://localhost:8081/getservicelist", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(session_id),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        //console.log(`****__ data: __****: `, data);

        localStorage.setItem("array_services", JSON.stringify(data));

        setArray_services(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

      
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    let session_id = {
      session_id: sessionID,
    };
    fetch("http://localhost:8081/getmnemonicsandtagsforabm", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(session_id),
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(`****__ data:__****: `, data);
        localStorage.setItem("mnemonicsAndTags", JSON.stringify(data));
        localStorage.setItem("mnemonics", JSON.stringify(data.mnemonics));
        localStorage.setItem("tags", JSON.stringify(data.tags));
        localStorage.setItem("tagsForMnemonics", JSON.stringify(data.tagsForMnemonics));
        setArray_services(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);
```

I await the return of the array accordingly

Comment: Your endpoint is returning an empty array

Comment: Do you mean that the server is returning an empty array?  Or that it's returning the expected data but you're losing that data somewhere in the client-side code?  Or something else?  Can you please clarify the specific debugging you've done and observations you've made?

Comment: server is returning an empty array

Comment: You have not provided any implementation for the endpoint you're calling, or any documentation for the endpoint, so it's difficult to analyze what's happening.  However, you're using a POST and the only data you're providing is a session ID.  It's likely that you're calling the endpoint incorrectly.  Would have expected some sort of error response, but it's possible that the endpoint is behaving as intended.  You really need to provide at the very least a [mre] if you want help debugging this.